# Bash Argument List too long error when passing a large file

Tags: bash

I am trying to run the script which takes a list file as an argument. The argument file is really big, it has some 200k lines. When i try to run the script, I get Argument list too long error. I know it is hitting more than maximum, is there any work-around to execute the script, apart from braking the file into smaller files?

Comment: Are you running `/path/to/yourscript yourfile` and getting this error? Or something like `/path/to/yourscript $(< yourfile)`?

Comment: Do you have control to edit the script so that it accepts a file **name**, or so it can read lines from stdin?

Comment: I am using /path/to/yourscript $(< yourfile).

Comment: I think it is not possible, the OS imposes a limit on the size of the command buffer.

Comment: Yes, i have the control to edit the script and now i am trying to read the file name as argument. Thanks a lot for the help @glennjackman 
while file read; do
done < $1

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to process the entire file in one process/one execution, you can use `xargs`:

```
xargs /path/to/your/script<file
```

That will execute `/path/to/your/script` multiple times, each time with the maximum possible number of subsequent lines from "file" as command-line arguments to the script.